# Can't run no one rails server after editing secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project worked in development good, but in production:

"Puma caught this error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)"

Then I edited the file "secrets.yml" and now I can't run no one rails server (this and other projects). 
[SSL connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3VBS.jpg)

rails s (any project which used puma):

```
HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2015-11-21 18:31:21 +0200: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/plain", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"2.11.1", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
```

rails s (any project which used webrick)

```
[2015-11-21 18:33:04] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1 [2015-11-21 18:33:04] INFO ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux] [2015-11-21 18:33:04] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=28129 port=3000 [2015-11-21 18:33:05] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03�[\x0E\x0ERqp'. [2015-11-21 18:33:05] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03a"|1�\f�I+d��J�<i]o\x1Ad�]v\x11N�wH��ҧ\x00\x00 �+�/\x00��\x14�\x13�\x15�'. [2015-11-21 18:33:05] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03��Vƿ�(�p\v�"\x03�Isj�|�;��xP'�&,���\x00\x00 �+�/\x00��\x14�\x13�\x15�'. [2015-11-21 18:33:06] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03\x06V���[Y�R$\x7F���c�H'. [2015-11-21 18:33:06] ERROR bad URI `�+�/\x00��\x14�\x13�\x15�'. [2015-11-21 18:33:06] ERROR bad URI `a��'. [2015-11-21 18:33:06] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x01�'*��[�����\x10r��t(�)�M������\x02��mG\x00\x00\x14�'. ^Z^C[2015-11-21 18:39:53] INFO going to shutdown ... [2015-11-21 18:39:53] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

---

Note: the project which i edited was cloned from github

Comment: Can you post your secrets?

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to connect over SSL (i.e. with HTTPS), but the server doesn’t understand it. It is trying to interpret the SSL handshake as the HTTP request, which results in the error.

Use plain HTTP: `http://localhost:3000`.